# CSS display:inline with margin vs position:relative

Tags: html, css

In my header I am looking to simply place a phone number, in between my logo on the left and my cart images on the right. So 3 divs of horizontal content.

To do this I have used a div with display:inline-block and a 100px margin after the logo. I have had to put a @media in the CSS to tidy up a bit when it goes mobile, as the big margin throws it a bit.

I know wonder whether the same could have been done easier with position:relative and some dimensions, this would also mean I wouldn't have to add much @media as the margin wouldn't throw it out.

So aligning and positioning horizontal content - Position or Margin/Display?

```
<div class="logo">
  <img src="mylogo.png">
  <div class="phonenumber">0111 111 111</div>
</div>

.phone{
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size:26px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I would consider margin to be first resort and relative to be last.

Comment: A flex box layout may more easily get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the `100px margin` is mandatory, but you could just fix this with `columns`. Every `column` in my example takes up `33.3% width` of the `row` and is `floated` to the left. I also made sure to `clear` the `floats` in order to maintain a proper layout on the rest of your page. The `text-align` properties I made are just for a better look.

```css
.row:after {
  clear:both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}

.phonenumber {
  text-align: center;
}

.cart {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column logo"><img src="mylogo.png"></div>
  <div class="column phonenumber">0111 111 111</div>
  <div class="column cart">blabla</div>
</div>
```

As to using media queries, I personally tend to stick to the most common widths and leave it at that.

```
// Mobile
@media (max-width: 767px) {}
// Tablet portrait (iPad based)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}
// Tablet landscape (iPad based)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}
// Desktop
@media (min-width: 1025px) {}
```

Comment: If you have a large logo and go to mobile, how does it affect the 33% width placings.

Comment: Why float when you are using a table layout? Just use `table-cell` for the individual `div`s.

Comment: In my example, the logo will never be bigger than `33.3%`, not even on mobile. in this case you would use the mobile media query I added in and give them a width of 100%. Like:  http://jsfiddle.net/e1L1gozm/2/

Comment: @Abhitalks Why use table-cell when you can float? I mean, they're just different approaches to the same problem.

Comment: Ahh.. @SteynvanEsveld, I misread your code in a hurry, I thought you were using a table layout, when actually you were just clearing the float.

Comment: @Abhitalks Oooh, yeah I see your confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a table layout.

A `display: table` on your `row` and `display: table-cell` on your `column`s, and that's it. No need to meddle with margins and widths and floats. Automatically responsive as long as your logo and text are not too big. Otherwise just add a media query to handle that.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hu6o5jv4/1/**

**Snippet**:

```css
.row { display: table; width: 100%; margin-top: 32px; }
.column { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
.phonenumber { text-align: center; }
.cart { text-align: right; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column logo"><img src="//placehold.it/72x48?text=logo"></div>
  <div class="column phonenumber">0111 111 111</div>
  <div class="column cart"><img src="//placehold.it/72x48?text=cart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would using "row" conflict with Bootstrap use of rows, if used on a bootstrap site. Or would we be re-writing this in Bootstrap syntax? The site I am using uses Bootstrap, but not in the header

Comment: (1) If you are using Bootstrap, you should have specified that in your question! This changes everything. (2) I can't understand the statement *I am using uses Bootstrap, but not in the header* - How can you not use Bootstrap in just header but use it in rest of the page? (3) If you are sure that you are not using Bootstrappy styles for your header, then just use another name for the class instead of `row`.